# Understanding convergence rate for a iterative scheme

Tags: numerical-methods

For a given we denote the error $e_k = x_k - x^*$, and the convergence rate of the iterative scheme is $r$ so that

$$ \lim \frac{ ||e_{k+1} || }{ || e_k ||^r } = C $$

where $C$ is finite and positive.

Im trying to understand how to effectively use this definition. For example, take Newton;s method to find a root $f(x) = x$. The iteration is given by

$$ x_{k+1} = x_k - \frac{ f(x_k) }{f'(x_k) } $$

how can I compute the limit in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually done
using Taylor series
near the root.

If
$x_{k+1} = x_k - \frac{ f(x_k) }{f'(x_k) }
$
and
$f(x_k)$
is small 
and
$f'(x_k)$ is not small
then,
since
$f(x+h)
\approx f(x)+hf'(x)+O(h^2f''(x))
$
for small $h$,

$\begin{array}\\
f(x_{k+1})
&=f(x_k - \dfrac{ f(x_k) }{f'(x_k) })\\
&=f(x_k) - (\dfrac{ f(x_k) }{f'(x_k) })f'(x_k)+O((\dfrac{ f(x_k) }{f'(x_k) })^2f''(x_k))\\
&=O((\dfrac{ f(x_k) }{f'(x_k) })^2f''(x_k))\\
\text{so that}\\
\dfrac{f(x_{k+1})}{f(x_k)^2}
&=O(\dfrac{ f''(x_k) }{f'(x_k)^2 })\\
\end{array}
$

This shows that,
if both $f'$ and $f''$
are non-zero at the root,
the convergence is exactly quadratic.

Note:
None of this is original.